# Need a more elegant solution of using templatefile

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create bucket policies using a few templates, and dynamically passing in the name of the Principals. I did get it working, but I feel like there should be an easier and natural way of doing it than using flatten and a temporary variable like I did. Also I can't add `policy_principals_read  = ["ignore"]` and `policy_principals_write = ["ignore"]` to all the existing buckets (well that'd be super ugly)

The output produced is later imported by another module, hence the extra variables in the output shouldn't be a problem. The below code should be a reproducible example. Thank you for your time!

locals.tf

```
locals {

  principals = {
    "n-prod" = [
      "role/NP",
    ]
    "n-staging" = [
      "role/NS",
    ]
    "p-ro-roles" = [
      "p-dev",
      "p-prod",
    ]
    "ignore" = []
  }

  bucket_defaults = {
    server-data = {
      policy_name = "allow_read_only"
      policy_principals = [
        "p-ro-roles",
        "n-prod",
        "n-staging"
      ]
      policy_principals_read  = ["ignore"]
      policy_principals_write = ["ignore"]
    }

    client-data = {
      policy_name            = "allow_read_write"
      policy_principals      = []
      policy_principals_read = ["p-ro-roles"]
      policy_principals_write = [
        "n-prod",
        "n-staging"
      ]
    }
  }

  buckets = merge({
    for bucket_name, settings in local.bucket_defaults : bucket_name =>
    merge(settings, {
      policy = templatefile("policies/${settings.policy_name}.json.tmpl", {
        principals_read = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([settings.policy_principals_read, "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        principals_write = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([settings.policy_principals_write, "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        principals = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([settings.policy_principals, "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        bucket_name = bucket_name
      })
    })
    }
  )
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "buckets" {
  value = local.buckets
}
```

policies/allow_read_only.json.tmpl

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Id" : "AllowBucketRO",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Sid" : "AllowBucketRO",
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Principal" : {
        "AWS" : ${jsonencode(principals)}
      },
      "Action" : [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource" : [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

policies/allow_read_write.json.tmpl

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id" : "AllowBucketRW",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowConsoleAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal" : {
        "AWS" : ${jsonencode(principals_write)}
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
        "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid" : "AllowBucketRO",
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Principal" : {
        "AWS" : ${jsonencode(principals_read)}
      },
      "Action" : [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource" : [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

Now I don't have to include `policy_principals_read` and `policy_principals_write` in `bucket_defaults' which is a relief. I'm using` try` to check if those attributes exist:

```
  buckets = merge({
    for bucket_name, settings in local.bucket_defaults : bucket_name =>
    merge(settings, {
      policy = templatefile("policies/${settings.policy_name}.json.tmpl", {
        principals_read = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([try(settings.policy_principals_read, ["ignore"]), "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        principals_write = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([try(settings.policy_principals_read, ["ignore"]), "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        principals = setunion([
          for principal in flatten([try(settings.policy_principals, ["ignore"]), "ignore"]) : local.principals[principal]
        ]...)
        bucket_name = bucket_name
      })
    })
    }
  )
```

But I'd like to find a better way to perform `flatten([try(settings.policy_principals_read, ["ignore"]), "ignore"])`

Comment: Would an example such as https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile#lists help?

Comment: Everything is helpful! Thank you, but mine doesn't feel like a good solution yet

Comment: You will not find much better solution, except that maybe hiding all your logic in the templates. If your solution works as intended and you understand it, then you should stick with it.

Comment: That makes sense! I do feel like separating this particular code block and playing around with it + sharing it online makes me understand the problem more, and further improve my solution in a way.